# Retrieving an array name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have used array name in form. this routes to the controller function shown below.

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{url('quiz/check')}}"
{!! csrf_field() !!} 

@foreach ($quiz as $q)

@if($q->level=='1')
{{ $q->qid }}.  
{{ $q->question }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='1'>     
{{ $q->opt1 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='2'>     
{{ $q->opt2 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='3'>    
{{ $q->opt3 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='4'>   
{{ $q->opt4 }}<br><br>
@endif
@endforeach        
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Get result</button>
                            </form>
```

which i am trying to retrieve in controller as:

```
public function check(Request $request)
  {
    $count=0; 
    $input=$request->all();
    $mycheck=$input['mycheck'];
    $ch = DB::select('select * from quiz where category="gk" ');
    return View('quiz.check',['quiz'=>$ch,'input'=>$input,'count'=>$count]);     
 }
```

view file `check.blade.php`

```
Results:
@foreach ($quiz as $q)

   @if(array_key_exists($q->qid, $mycheck) && $mycheck[$q->qid]==$q->answer)
      {{$count=$count+1}}

@endif

@endforeach        

You scored {{$count}}.
```

now, i am getting this error:

> undefined variable: mycheck in view file

Comment: That's not an "array name". "Array names" are `foo[]` or `foo[bar]`. What you have is a plain old name with an underscore in it.

Comment: What are you using `$mycheck` var in controller for? You are getting this error because you are trying to retrieve an index 'mycheck' when actually it looks like 'mycheck_1' or something.

Comment: Also, inside your @if on view file, you can't use double curly braces because it is already php. Actually it's not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: @deceze edited the question.

Comment: Now it's even less clear what your problem is exactly...

Comment: @deceze trying to select options from radio button and compare with actual  answer. `opt1`,`opt2`,`opt3`,`opt4``question`and `answer` are database columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `$mycheck` variable to view.

Replace this line:

```
return View('quiz.check',['quiz'=>$ch,'input'=>$input,'count'=>$count]);
```

With this:

```
return View('quiz.check',['quiz'=>$ch,'input'=>$input,'count'=>$count,'mycheck'=>$mycheck]);
```

Also, looks like You trying to access variable `$q` which is actually variable `$quiz` according to Your data passed to view.

Comment: i have used @foreach($quiz as $q).

Comment: And it displays `Results: 1 2 3 You scored 3.` how can i not display 1 2 3. i used `$count=$count+1` but failed.